# Valid "protocols" for HornetQ

Tags: java, jboss, jms, hornetq

I have some code like this for connecting to HornetQ.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4447");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pwd");

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
Destination destination = null;

try {
    Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
```

I inherited this, and am trying to get a better understanding of it. I haven't found documentation for the valid values where I have "remote://". I'm not sure if it's accurate to call that a protocol or not, but that's what it looks like. I've seen "jnp://" in other samples.

Is there an official list of valid values, and what they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to refer to specific JNDI Reference for specific versions. JBOSS AS 7.2 is covered here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/JNDI+Reference (note that in JBOSS AS 7.x, jnp is no longer supported, older JBOSS versions do support the jnp:// and access via the standard naming services).

Another link: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/Naming_on_JBoss-The_Naming_InitialContext_Factories.html.